# can i make a subdomain to point a different app in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

i am a newbie to Google app engine web application.there are two seperate gae web applications in which one application intended for staging and the other application used for live production purpose.we bought a domain for eg: example.com which we point to staging as
 www.staging-example.com(it is working fine). what i want to do is that with the same domain name can i make it to point to the live production app like for eg: www.live-example.com. is it possible?.if its possible please tell me how?. your answers will be very appreciable.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that `www.staging-example.com` and `www.live-example.com` are two completely different and independent domains apart from the fact that they are both `.com` domains.

Since app engine does not support naked domain redirection with SSL (`staging-example.com`, `live-example.com` would not work with SSL) you have to use subdomains anyway, like `staging.example.com` and `live.example.com`.

And yes that is possible and basically the exact same steps for each app. Since you set that up for your staging domain this should be a piece of cake for you. The steps are described in [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#using_subdomains), but the highlights are:

- Create a CNAME record for your subdomain which points to `ghs.googlehosted.com`
- Add the custom domain in your [apps project custom domain settings](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/appengine/settings/domains).